# rewrite URL .HTACCESS redirecting to original URL which should not

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I know that this question can be the **DUPLICATE** of another question but after all I was unable to find an appropriate answer for my question.

I am trying to rewrite `url` with `.htaccess` that is placed in the *root directory* of my *localhost*

The file contains this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !home
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !seller
RewriteRule   ^([^/]*)/$   stores/$1   [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^([^/]*)$   stores/$1   [NC,L]
```

**Problem:**
If the original url is as `http://localhost/stores/mystore` then it can be access as `http://localhost/mystore` but **this new url** redirecting it to **original url** as first which should not do.

How it can be solve?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `stores/mystore` points to a directory then `mod_dir` will add a trailing slash after your rewrite rules have executed.

Try these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# add trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(home|seller)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ stores/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.+[^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L]
```